# Make the table disappear with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, media-queries

These are the Js and Html codes:

```js
function div(window.matchMedia("(max-width:800px)")) {
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width:800px)")) {
        document.getElementById("invtable").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("invtable").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="widget widget-table action-table" id="invtable">
    <div class="widget-header"> <i class="icon-th-list"></i>
        <h3>Últimos Podcasts</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /widget-header -->
    <div class="widget-content">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr style="width:300px">
                    <th> Nº</th>
                    <th> Título da Postagem </th>
                    <th> DATA</th>
                    <th> Link</th>
                    <th> Descrição</th>
                    <th class="td-actions"> </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /widget-content --> 
</div>
```

I need this html table to disappear, as it does not respond to mobile devices.

I tried to use window.matchMedia, which is equivalent to Media Queries, but unfortunately I didn't get the expected result.

Comment: does this need to be done in JS?, in css you can use `@media screen and (min-width:800px) { // code}`

Comment: Hello, yes, but unfortunately I received the code for a model and I didn't understand it in the best way

Comment: I tried to use Media Queries (CSS), but the table does not respond

Comment: use `screen.width`,`if (screen.width > 800px) { //code }`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't respond to mobile device"?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried using: screen.width, if (screen.width <1000px) {
      Window.alert ('Hello')}, but it did not work in google's mobile preview.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language haha, I mean the table is not responsive.

Comment: I mean, it's not in the right format on the page, but it breaks when it shrinks.

Comment: `<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
NOW TABLE DOESN'T HAVE TO BE HIDDEN
  </table>
</div>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it didn't work because of the css conflict or something, but thank you very much, people who help are making a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for `.matches`

```js
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width:800px)").matches) {
    document.getElementById("invtable").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("invtable").style.display = "none";
  }
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/andreasschrottenbaum/pen/eYzbPmw works for me

Comment: I saw that it worked, thank you very much, you have no idea how you helped me.